# Which function will identify the name of an R variable's enclosing environment?

Tags: r

I've been reading about R environments, and I'm trying to test my understanding with a simple example:

```
> f <- function() {
+   x <- 1
+   environment(x)
+ }
> 
> f()
NULL
```

I'm assuming this means that the object x is enclosed by the environment named NULL, but when I try to list all the objects in that environment, R displays an error message:

```
> ls(NULL)
Error in as.environment(pos) : using 'as.environment(NULL)' is defunct
```

So I'm wondering if there's a built-in function I can use on the command line that will return the environment name given the object name.  I tried this:

```
> environment(x)
Error in environment(x) : object 'x' not found
```

but that returned an error as well.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `x` is destroyed when the function is done executing

Comment: The `environment` function returns the environment of a `function` object, and not the one of an arbitrary object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables created in function calls are destroyed when the function finishes executing (unless you specifically create them in other persistent environments).  As @joran pointed out, when a function is called, a temporary environment is created where local variables are defined, and is destroyed when the function is done executing (that memory is freed).  However, as @MrFlick pointed out, if the function returns a function, the returned function maintains a reference to the environment it was created in.  You can read more about '[scope](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping)', ['stack', and 'heap'](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html).  In R there are various ways you can define your variables into specified environments.

```
f <- function()  {
    x <<- 1  # create x in the global environment (or change it if it's there)
    ## or `assign` x to a value
    ## assign(x, value=1, envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
environment(f)  # where was f defined?
exists("x", envir=.GlobalEnv)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Perhaps another way to phrase your comment above would be to say that when executing `f`, R creates an environment for `f` that lasts for the duration of the function execution. But once `f` is done, the environment (and all that is in it) is lost.

Comment: @joran Well, a function's environment can exist after the function exists if that function returns another function or a formula. `f<-function(x) {a<-x+1; function() a }; environment(f(5))`. In this case a new environment is created each time the function runs and it continues to exist after the function exits as well as the variable `a` inside it. `x<-f(5); x()`

Comment: @MrFlick True, though as you show you have to explicitly create that behavior.

Comment: @joran Ah, i see you were talking about that specific `f` and not all functions in general.

Comment: @MrFlick I prefer that interpretation over me just be careless. ;)

Answer (score 6):

The package `pryr` has some nice functions to do these kind of things. For example, there is a function called `where` which will give you the environment of an object:

```
library(pryr)
f <- function() {
    x <- 1
    where("x")
}
f()
<environment: 0x0000000013356f50>
```

So the environment of `x` was the temporary enviroment created by function `f()`. As people have said before, this enviroment is detroyed after you run the function, so it will give you a different result each time you run `f()`.